# How to create an instance object of a Model in Django that was created by a ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, html

I'm facing difficulties in creating an instance of a model created by a ManyToManyField.

This is what I have in models.py:

```
class Attendee(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="attendee")

class Activity(models.Model):
    attendee = models.ManyToManyField(Attendee, related_name="attendees",null=True, blank=True)
```

I've tried this function in views.py but it doesnt work:

```
def registerAttende(request,pk):
    act = Activity.objects.get(pk=pk)
    act.save()
    act.attendee.add(student=request.user.pk) # This is the line causing the error
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html')
```

I get the following error:

> "TypeError at /5
>   add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'student' "

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for manyto many try it:

```
def registerAttende(request,pk):
    act = Activity.objects.get(pk=pk)
    act.save()
    # Get Attendee or create it, in the '_' boolvalue created, don need now
    attendee, _ = Attendee.objects.get_or_create(student=request.user)
    act.attendee.add(attendee)
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html')
```

for more details read the [get-or-create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) and [many2many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work unfortunately. I also referred to the doc and made some changes in my code as you'll see in my updated question. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and why it's not working.

Comment: Yes, I'm not getting any errors. The only problem is that no change is happening in the database.

Comment: What is a correct url form action that calls registerAttende?

Comment: try `{% url 'register' %}`

Comment: But I need to pass an id also. I tried {% url 'register' activity.id %} and got the NoReverseMatch at / error

Comment: so you have many errors in your code, you need to rebuild your code from new.

Comment: Can you please check my updated question. I fixed all errors and I'm stuck with one. How do I fix adding to the model?

Comment: glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

you are passing activity.id in get but trying to retrieve by request.post

use`<input type='hidden' name='id' value='{{activity.id}}' />` in form